# RegExp to catch bit stuffing

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regular expression to catch bit stuffing - after 5 consecutive bits of the same value one opposite bit is inserted.

e.g

input: 00000100000100

regex output: 000001, 000001

input: 00000111110111

regex output: 000001, 111110

I did this /([01])\1{4}[01]/ but it catches 6 consecutive bits and when the last bit is opposite

https://regex101.com/r/QdoVbK/2

Comment: Why not make it simple - `0{5}1|1{5}0`?

Comment: Like this? `([01])\1{4}(?!\1)` https://regex101.com/r/l13TWy/1

Comment: @Prasanna not sure why I didn't thought about that. In the second example the count should start from the stuffed bit, how can you do that?

Comment: The second example has 4 zeroes between the 1's. If there were 5 https://regex101.com/r/C9YHbg/1

Comment: @The fourth bird, your regexp only catches 5 consecutive bits. Please see my edit.

Comment: Perhaps with a capturing group inside a lookahead `(?=(10000[01]|[01]00001|01111[01]|[01]11110))` https://regex101.com/r/kaw4au/1

Comment: I am confused about desired output. Could you give an example with given input bit pattern, what the bit pattern is after first match & bit insertion, after second, third, etc.

Comment: @Peter Thoeny, I edited the question, hope its clear now

Comment: Still confused. With simple 5-bit bit stuffing, the opposite bit is inserted into the stream after 5 consecutive identical bits, e.g. `00000100000100` turns into `0000011000001100`, but in your example `00000100000100` turns into `000001`?

Comment: My example is already with the stuffed bit, e.g. 00000**1**00000**1**00 the 1 are the stuffed bits...

Comment: @Dangur Perhaps like this `(?=(([01])\2{4}(?!\2)[01]))` https://regex101.com/r/5UBPEj/1 See the capture group 1 values in green at the right side of the regex101 link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might use a positive lookahead with 2 capture groups. Repeat 5 of the same values in group 2, followed by a sixth when it is not the same as the value in group 2.

The whole value is in capture group 1.

```
(?=(([01])\2{4}(?!\2)[01]))
```

**Explanation**

- `(?=` Positive lookahead

  - `(` Capture **group 1**

    - `([01])\2{4}` Capture **group 2**, match either `0` or `1` and match the same value 4 times
    - `(?!\2)` Negative lookahead, assert not the value of group 2 directly to the right
    - `[01]` Match either `0` or `1`
  - `)` Close group 1
- `)` Close lookahead

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5UBPEj/1/)

```js
const regex = /(?=(([01])\2{4}(?!\2)[01]))/g;
[
  "00000100000100",
  "00000111110111"
].forEach(s => console.log(Array.from(s.matchAll(regex), m => m[1])));
```